# Can i send variable in php to anoter page?

Tags: php, html

This is my code but it doesn't work (error 500)

```
while ($dbarr = mysqli_fetch_array($result))    
{
    echo $dbarr['qno']; 
    echo '<a href=show_detail.php?item=' . $dbarr[qno] . '>' . $dbarr[ans] . '</a>';
    
    echo $dbarr['qname'],"</a>&nbsp;";      
    echo $dbarr['qcount'] . "<br>\n";   

}
```

Comment: array keys should be quoted, try `echo '<a href=show_detail.php?item=' . $dbarr['qno'] . '>' . $dbarr['qno'] . '</a>';`

Comment: it's HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: What gives you 500?  Running this script, or clicking the button?  We can't really do much without seeing the rest of your code.  Have you run your code at the command line to see what error you get?  Is `qno` a variable, or a literal key for the array?  And note that @Raxi's suggestion has `'qno'` for the second reference, where you had `'ans'`.

Comment: You'd have to look in your servers' (php or webserver)logfile to see what the actual error is in that case.

Comment: The problem likely is that those array keys didn't exist, i just copied it from your original.

Comment: The problem likely is that those array keys didn't exist, i just copied it from your original. If you're using a modern PHP then a spiffier way of doing it would be:
 `printf('<a href="show_detail.php?item=%s>%s</a>', (isset($dbarr[$k = 'qno']) ? htmlentities($dbarr[$k]) : 'defaultItem'), (isset($dbarr[$k = 'ans']) ? htmlentities($dbarr[$k]) : 'defaultItem') );`

Comment: test is a text if i do echo '<a href=show_detail.php?item=' . $dbarr[qno] . '>test</a>'; it's work but test is hyperlink but i need too call $dbarr[ans] it's data from datbase

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 is often caused by an error in the PHP code.

Google for `enable php error logging`.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Check if `$dbarr` contains the expected keys:

```
while ($dbarr = mysqli_fetch_array($result))    
{
    print_r($dbarr);
}
```